# T-SQL Dynamic columns Dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table like on this photo.

[image]

I want to be like:

```
EventTypeID|CreatedBy |2016-03-01 |2016-03-02  |2016-03-03|...
6          |    2     |     1     |      2     |      0   |... 
9          |    4     |     0     |      1     |      3   |...
...
```

I've tried this T-SQL:

```
DECLARE 
    @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @startdate datetime,
    @enddate datetime,
    @paramdef nvarchar(max)

SET @startdate = '2013-02-01'
SET @enddate = '2013-05-10';
SET @paramdef = '@startdate datetime, @enddate datetime';

SELECT 
    @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(convert(varchar(10), [Date], 120)) 
                   FROM AdeccoView
                   --where datein > @startdate
                   --    and datein <= @enddate
                   GROUP BY [Date]
                   ORDER BY [Date]
                   FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')

SET @query = N'SELECT EventTypeID, '+ @cols + '
        from 
        (
            select EventTypeID, 
                [Date] = convert(varchar(10), [Date], 120), 
                dttime = cast(cast(timeout  as varchar(5)),
                row_number() over(partition by ViewID, [Date] order by  [Date]) seq
            from AdeccoViews
            --where datein > @startdate
               -- and datein <= @enddate
        ) x
        pivot 
        (
            max(dttime)
            for [Date] in ('+@cols+')
        ) p '

exec sp_executesql @query, @paramdef, @startdate = @startdate, @enddate =      @enddate;
```

EDIT:

This is my editied version..it seems to be good, but I am struggling with local variable @v_columns -  Incorrect syntax near "+@v_Columns+". Expecting '.', ID, or QUOTED_ID.

```
DECLARE 
@v_Columns VARCHAR(MAX),
@v_StartDate DATETIME = '2011-11-01',
@v_EndDate DATETIME = '2011-11-05',
@v_Query VARCHAR(MAX)

--pivot and delimit values

SELECT @v_Columns = COALESCE(@v_Columns,'[') + convert(varchar, [Date], 111) + '],[' 
FROM 
(SELECT DISTINCT [Date] FROM AdeccoView) th
WHERE
th.[Date] BETWEEN @v_StartDate AND @v_EndDate

--delete last two chars of string (the ending ',[')

SET @v_Columns = SUBSTRING(@v_Columns, 1, LEN(@v_Columns)-2)



SELECT Name,[Event]
FROM 
(SELECT ViewID, emp.EmployeeD, c.EventTypeID, c.CreatedBy, emp.Name,c.[Date],     [Event]
 FROM
  AdeccoView c
  left join EventType r
  on c.EventTypeID = r.EventTypeID
  left join Employee emp on c.CreatedBy = emp.EmployeeD) p
PIVOT
(COUNT (EventTypeID) FOR [Date] IN ( '+ @v_Columns +' )) AS pvt
ORDER BY pvt.ViewID;
```

EDIT with TOTAL column:

I am trying to set up Total column, but data ain't good. I used COUNT(*) over partition:

```
DECLARE 
@cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@selcols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@startdate datetime,
@enddate datetime,
@paramdef nvarchar(max)

SET @startdate = '2013-02-01'
SET @enddate = '2013-05-10';
SET @paramdef = '@startdate datetime, @enddate datetime';


SELECT 
@selcols = STUFF((SELECT ','+'ISNULL(' + QUOTENAME(convert(varchar(10),  [Date], 120)) + ', 0) AS ' +  QUOTENAME(convert(varchar(10), [Date], 120)) 
               FROM AdeccoView
               --where datein > @startdate
               --    and datein <= @enddate
               GROUP BY [Date]
               ORDER BY [Date]
               FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')


SELECT 
@cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(convert(varchar(10), [Date], 120)) 
               FROM AdeccoView
               --where datein > @startdate
               --    and datein <= @enddate
               GROUP BY [Date]
               ORDER BY [Date]
               FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')

SET @query = N'SELECT CreatedBy,Name, Surname,EventTypeID,Event, '+ @selcols + ',Total
    from 
    (
        select av.EventTypeID,av.CreatedBy,emp.Name,emp.Surname,Event,
            convert(varchar(10), [Date], 120) [Date],
            row_number() over(PARTITION BY [date],av.EventTypeID,av.CreatedBy   order BY av.EventTypeID,av.CreatedBy ) m,
            Count(*) over(partition by av.EventTypeID) Total
        from AdeccoView av
        left join EventType et on et.EventTypeID = av.EventTypeID
        left join Employee emp on av.CreatedBy = emp.EmployeeD

    ) x
    pivot 
    (
        max(m)
        for [Date] in ('+@cols+')
    ) p '

exec sp_executesql @query, @paramdef, @startdate = @startdate, @enddate =@enddate;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this

```
DECLARE 
    @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @selcols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @startdate datetime,
    @enddate datetime,
    @paramdef nvarchar(max)

SET @startdate = '2013-02-01'
SET @enddate = '2013-05-10';
SET @paramdef = '@startdate datetime, @enddate datetime';


SELECT 
    @selcols = STUFF((SELECT ','+'ISNULL(' + QUOTENAME(convert(varchar(10), [Date], 120)) + ', 0) AS ' +  QUOTENAME(convert(varchar(10), [Date], 120)) 
                   FROM AdeccoView
                   --where datein > @startdate
                   --    and datein <= @enddate
                   GROUP BY [Date]
                   ORDER BY [Date]
                   FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')


SELECT 
    @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(convert(varchar(10), [Date], 120)) 
                   FROM AdeccoView
                   --where datein > @startdate
                   --    and datein <= @enddate
                   GROUP BY [Date]
                   ORDER BY [Date]
                   FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')

SET @query = N'SELECT EventTypeID, '+ @selcols + '
        from 
        (
            select EventTypeID,CreatedBy,
                convert(varchar(10), [Date], 120) [Date],
                row_number() over(PARTITION BY [date],EventTypeID,CreatedBy order BY EventTypeID,CreatedBy ) m
            from AdeccoView
            --where datein > @startdate
               -- and datein <= @enddate
        ) x
        pivot 
        (
            max(m)
            for [Date] in ('+@cols+')
        ) p '

exec sp_executesql @query, @paramdef, @startdate = @startdate, @enddate =@enddate;
```

Comment: Nope, I ran on errors: on line 10 and line 1 - Incorrect syntax near '2016-03-03'. Also: Incorrect syntax near 'x'.

Comment: But with edited post you want to obtain different data from first post.If you use variables you have to use exec sp_executesql because is dynamic query.

Comment: Great work! It works! Just a question: If I want to group by CreatedBy (employee) as variable and to check is it null or not null (I am planning to create stored procedure for this query), I would just add groupBy in @query?

Comment: Just to be clear, I want to implement additional variable, which I will fill from mvc5 program, like a filter which employee has entered on which days EventTypeID. Thanks again. You helped me a lot!

Comment: Yes you add GROUP BY Statement at the end of @query. but you must remove data columns from select because there aren't include in aggregation functions. Ok but if you use that variable to filter data i think you have to introduce WHERE statement in this block (
            select EventTypeID,CreatedBy,
                convert(varchar(10), [Date], 120) [Date],
                row_number() over(PARTITION BY [date],EventTypeID,CreatedBy order BY EventTypeID,CreatedBy ) m
            from AdeccoView
            --where statement
        ) x

Comment: Thank you. I will try. I will let you know, if I succeeded!

Comment: It works perfectly! I am curious, how would I insert on the end, after dynamic dates columns a SUM function which will summarize in each row? I am trying to, insert in pivot another function SUM(m) in (sum1) which i called my column sum1. Thanks

Comment: I think you have to use the result of PIVOT in this way:SELECT A.your_column, SUM(A.column_to_sum) FROM (select extracted from pivot) A GROUP BY A.your_column

Comment: I tried, but it shows me an error. Could you be so kind to update your code, it would be for me a great help! Thanks.

Comment: Cristian, please find my edit code. I think that I'm near to solution. Thanks.

Comment: `count(*) over(partition by av.CreatedBy,av.EventTypeId) Total` that worked!

Comment: Great solution! Excuse me but i cannot answer you yesterday.